# Difference between text_size and texture_size in kivy label properties

Tags: kivy

When setting up properties in kivy label, there are texture_size and text_size. What is the difference between them?

Comment: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/label.py

Answer (score 5):

`texture_size` is a dynamically generated dimension for Label in kivy. It depends on the text length and font size. It is parameter value for the attribute `size`.

```
Label:
    size: self.texture_size
```

`text_size` is an attribute for Label. Here you can hard-code the size of the Label.

```
Label:    
    text_size: cm(6), cm(4)
```